# Magento 2.1 CE Installed but front/backend not loading/working

Tags: magento2, php

I am new to Magento and trying to install it myself but can't see it working after installing it successfully.

I followed [**Amazon instructions**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html) and installed PHP56, MySQL 5.7 & phpMyAdmin and then followed the following steps to install [**Magento 2.1 CE:**](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/zip_install.html)

sudo su

vi /etc/php.ini
?always_populate_raw_post_data
I
always_populate_raw_post_data = -1
:wq
service httpd restart
sudo yum install php56-intl –y
service httpd restart
mkdir /var/www/html/magento2ce
upload magento tar file to /var/www/html/magento2ce and unzip using tar command
cd /var/www/html/magento2ce
tar zxf Magento-CE-2.1.1-2016-08-29-06-31-39.tar.gz
And before installation I used following command to assign permissions to magento folders: cd /var/www/html/magento2ce && find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \; && find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \; && chown -R :apache . && chmod u+x bin/magento

And after all that I stared Setup Wizard which ran successfully.

But nothing works when I try to access front/backend.

Can any one please let me what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the root path in your magento vhost file to /var/www/magento2/pub , where /var/www/magento2 is your magento 2 installation path.

Comment: is this solution is before running installation wizard or after?

Comment: After the installation

Comment: Sorry I am new to this, Could send me the name & location of this file?

Answer (score 1):

1- Modify the app/etc/di.xml file by changing the following content:

Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink

To:

Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy

2- Remove cahce from the cache folder

sudo rm -rf /var/www/html/magento2ce/var/cache/

3- sudo php /var/www/html/magento2ce/bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: is this solution is before running installation wizard or after?

Comment: Throwing following exception while running 3rd step: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /var/www/html/magento2ce/vendor/oyejorge/less.php/lib/Less/Parser.php on line 740
/var/www/html/magento2ce/vendor/oyejorge/less.php/lib/Less/Visitor/processExtends.php on line 221
/var/www/html/magento2ce/vendor/oyejorge/less.php/lib/Less/Tree/Selector.php on line 61
Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors for more info on how to handle out of memory errors.[root@ip-172-31-26-197 mag

Comment: Hi There, any update on this?

Comment: Please use this  below command
sudo php -dmemory_limit=6G /var/www/html/magento2ce/bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: Hi Hari, above command worked this time but I still can't see the front-end fully working and back-end is still throwing 404 error, following are the links: http://ec2-54-194-66-114.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/magento2ce/, http://ec2-54-194-66-114.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/magento2ce/admin/